# Inconsistent alpha channel in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm building an educational tool using *planes, extruded splines,* and *cylinder geometries*. Planes have a texture map and the rest are either basic or Lambert materials.

- Texture map on planes in the only map and it does have an alpha
  channel.
- Texture map has been tested as .GIF and .PNG
- **All objects have "transparent: true"**
- renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );

NOTE: this is the exact same problem listed at the following link. It has not been solved and my Rep isn't high enough to comment.

[in three.js, alpha channel works inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857233/in-three-js-alpha-channel-works-inconsistently)

As mmaclaurin noted, it could be a change based in draw order and camera location. I am using THREE.TrackballControls and limiting camera movement to two axes.

Adding or removing the BasicMaterial for wireframe does not change the issue.

**Thank you for your time reading this and any help you can offer!**

Example of plane object:

```
var T4map = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'medium_T4.png' );
    var T4Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { opacity: .96, transparent:true, map: T4map } );
    var T4Geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(810, 699, 10, 10);
    var T4 = new THREE.Mesh(T4Geometry, T4Material);
    T4.position.y = -CNspacing;
    T4.doubleSided = true;
    scene.add(T4);
```

Example of extruded spline geometry where problem is most noticeable:

```
var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xaaff00, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true } ),           
      mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
      mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
      parent.add( mesh );
```

Comment: New observation: it might only be happening below y=0

Comment: Moving all objects to y>0 didn't help. However, if I move the camera through all y positions to observe the lack of alpha, the effect eventually stops. Sounds like a drawing issue...

Comment: Problem stops but transparency is lost and gone forever (until refresh)

Answer (score 3):

Try to play around with `depthTest`. Usually this would help:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { side:THREE.BackSide,map:texture,transparency:true, opacity:0.9, depthWrite: false, depthTest: false });
```

There are many other questions related to your subject, for ex.: [transparent bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165345/three-js-webgl-serious-bug-of-transparent-planes-hiddening-other-planes-behind/)

Answer (score 0):

Was just going to comment but its too long:

Objects that are marked with transparent = true, are painters sorted based on their centroid, and drawn back to front so that the transparency layers mostly correctly. Make sure your mesh.geometries have proper computeBoundingBox() and computeBoundingSphere() applied to them before adding them... if that doesn't fix your problem, then try using material.alphaTest = 0.5 on your materials.. this works well for things that are mostly on/off alpha.. like masks... but if you have smooth gradations of transparency from 0 to 1 in your textures, you may see fringes where the alpha test threshholding happens.